# How to know when a deposit happens on a stripe virtual account

Tags: stripe-payments

I generated a stripe ACH account as highlighed in this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration/virtual-bank-numbers). How do I get notified when this deposit happens so I can give user value for there payment.

I am looking at using webhooks but I can not find what the structure of data stripe will send looks like.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you there are able to register  API hooks for events. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints

Comment: Yes I know that but what does the body of the webhook request body look like, I can not find any documentation for that.

Comment: It would be a "source transaction" object , there's an example of what those look like here : https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ach-credit-transfer#source-transactions 
the best option here is to test it in testmode (https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ach-credit-transfer#testing-ach-credit-transfer-payments) and see what events happen.